# Milnor exact sequence for homology of hopf algebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras, homology

Let $K$ be a field and $\mathrm{Hopf}^K_{E_\infty}$ the $\infty$-category of
homotopy-coherent hopf algebras over $K$ that are coherently commutative and cocommutative.
Precisely, $\mathrm{Hopf}^K_{E_\infty}$ is the $\infty$-category of abelian group objects (in the derived sense) in the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Coalg}_{E_\infty}^K$ of $E_\infty$-coalgebras over $K$.
Homology defines a functor $$H_*: D(K) \to \mathrm{grVect}_K $$
from the derived $\infty$-category of $K$ to the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $K$-vector spaces.
By the Künneth theorem homology $H_*: D(K) \to \mathrm{grVect}_K $ is symmetric monoidal
and so induces a functor $$H_*:\mathrm{Hopf}^K_{E_\infty} \to \mathrm{grHopf}_K, $$
where $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$ is the category of commutative and cocommutative $\mathbb{Z}$-graded hopf algebras over $K.$

The category $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$ is abelian and so it makes sense to talk about exact sequences
in $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$. Moreover it makes sense to talk about lim^1 of a tower in $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$.
Given a tower $A_\bullet$ in $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$ is there for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a short exact sequence $$ 0 \to lim^1(H_{n+1}(A_\bullet)) \to H_{n}(holim(A_\bullet)) \to lim(H_{n}(A_\bullet)) \to 0 $$ in the abelian category $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$, where the (homotopy) inverse limits are taken in
$\mathrm{Hopf}^K_{E_\infty}$ and $\mathrm{grHopf}_K$?